# Get value from textview in another method

Tags: java, android

I want to get value from textview in another method, which is :

```
 public SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float pressure_value = 0.0f;
        float height = 0.0f;
        if (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType())
        {
            pressure_value = event.values[0];
            height = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,pressure_value);
        }
        String value = String.valueOf(height);
        txtBaro.setText(value);
    }
};
```

And my method is :

```
public void onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state){
//this is where i want to get value from txtBaro.
if (value from txtBaro > 45)
{
    // do something
}
 }
```

Any idea ?

**EDITED :**
I want to get value '*value*' from **sensorEventListener** (string) and passing it to **onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state)**

Comment: Maybe use a static variable to store value. Still not quite understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem you want to save the value that you pass to txtBaro. Just create a variable like

```
public static int valueOftxtBaro;
```

And then just save your textview's value, add

```
valueOftxtBaro = Integer.parseInt(txtBaro.getText().toString());
```

After

```
txtBaro.setText(value);
```

Then use it wherever you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
int value;
try {
    value = Integer.parseInt(txtBaro.getText().toString());
    if(value > 45){
        // do something
    }
} catch (Exception e){

}
```

Comment: where do i declare TextView txtBaro ?